# How to focus on input field loaded from component in Svelte?

Tags: input, autofocus, svelte

After loading the component that has input filed inside it. How can I focus on that particular field?

**TextField.svelte**

```
<script>

  export let label = ''
  export let name = ''
  export let placeholder = ''
  export let value = ''

</script>

<div class="field">
  <label for={name}>{label}</label>
  <input {placeholder} type="text" {name} bind:value={value} >
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
  import TextField from './TextField'
  import {onMount} from 'svete'

  onMount(() => {
    // This line is funny.. I know
    document.querySelector('[name="firstname"]').focus()
  })

</script>

<TextField label="First Name" name="firstname" />
```

Comment: My question has typos. See below answer for reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to focus on newly added inputs in Svelte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257499/how-to-focus-on-newly-added-inputs-in-svelte)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get a reference to the input DOM node with `bind:this` and export it as a prop and use it in the parent component.

**Example**

```html
<!-- TextField.svelte -->
<script>
  export let label = '';
  export let name = '';
  export let placeholder = '';
  export let value = '';
  export let ref = null;
</script>

<div class="field">
  <label for={name}>{label}</label>
  <input {placeholder} type="text" {name} bind:value={value} bind:this={ref} >
  <slot></slot>
</div>

<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import TextField from './TextField.svelte';
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
  let ref;
    
  onMount(() => {
    ref.focus(); 
  });      
</script>

<TextField label="First Name" name="firstname" bind:ref />
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? ``ref.focus()`` doesn't seem to work for me whereas I'm able to change other properties of element using ``ref``.

Comment: What is 'ref' short for? It might be clearer to use a better variable name.

Comment: @mikemaccana - ref just short for reference, but it's commonly used in this context so for the sake of an example should be fine.

Comment: @Lissy93 what is `ref` a reference to? An element (just guessing)? It would be clearer to use `textfield` or `textfieldElement` or some other full word.

Answer (score 6):

You have several typos actually in the `App.svelte`.

First, importing the component.

```js
import TextField from './TextField'
```

That should be:

```js
import TextField from './TextField.svelte';
```

Second, the Svelte package itself.

```js
import {onMount} from 'svete'
```

That should be:

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
```

Okay, now we are ready to code.

Since `autofocus` attribute should be avoided, we may use Tholle's answer as reference.

In the `TextField.svelte`, you handle the *autofocus*.

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let focused = false;
    export let label = '';
    export let name = '';
    export let placeholder = '';
    export let value = '';

    let elm;

    onMount(function() {
        elm.focus();
    });
</script>

<div class="field">
    <label for={name}>{label}</label>
    <input {placeholder} type="text" {name} bind:value={value} bind:this={elm}/>
    <slot/>
</div>
```

In the `App.svelte`, you call the component.

```js
<script>
  import TextField from './TextField.svelte';
</script>

<TextField label="First Name" name="firstname" focused/>
<TextField label="Last Name" name="lastname" focused/>
```

The demo available on the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c7d426bf1e204fe584b4ce0c292ebc3a?version=3.7.0).

The difference between my answer and Tholle's is that `focus()` should be executed in the `TextField` component since it is component specific functionality.

Comment: Not editing my question for silly typos so that the precious lines you wrote remain relevant :)

Comment: Notice that it's not the `autofocus` attribute that should be avoided, but rather _autofocus_ itself, which is what this answer does anyway. All this does is get rid of the warning. Also, you should have an `await tick()` before calling focus otherwise your element may not exist. Lastly, you probably wanted to check for `if (focused)` before calling `elm.focus()`, otherwise that prop is useless.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `autofocus` attribute.

```
<script>

  export let label = ''
  export let name = ''
  export let placeholder = ''
  export let value = ''

</script>

<div class="field">
  <label for={name}>{label}</label>
  <input {placeholder} type="text" {name} bind:value={value} autofocus > // <-- here
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

But as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57258701/11852431), it's probably not a good idea from an accessibility standpoint.

Comment: Nowadays that'll trigger a warning: `A11y: Avoid using autofocussvelte(a11y-autofocus)`. So as the OP stated, probably not the way to go.